# How do I get the adjacency Matrix from a random graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am using the command

```
g = RandomGraph[{8, 13}]; 
GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

to plot a random graph with n nodes and l edges.

Once the program has generated it, I would like to get the adjacency matrix of the graph, eventually change it and re-plot the new graph.

I can't find the solution to this simple question.

Comment: …and for some strange reason, you couldn't find [`AdjacencyMatrix[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I found it, and I even used it... The problem is that when I do AdjacencyMatrix[g] \\ MatrixForm and then copy paste the matrix into GraphPlot[], even if I change the matrix he doesn't change the graph.

Comment: I see, so you were also unable to find `AdjacencyGraph[]`…

Comment: No, I was also able to find it, because I am stupid, but not that stupid. It doesn't change the problem. Let me know what I'm doing wrong: I first write for instance g = RandomGraph[{8, 13}]; GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True]. Then I write AdjacencyMatrix[g] // MatrixForm and I get a matrix. Last, I use either AdjacencyGraph or GraphPlot and copy paste the matrix, change the matrix and hit enter. But the outcome is the initial matrix...

Comment: I was in no way, shape, or form saying that you were stupid, but certainly what you've told me just now probably ought to have been in the question in the first place. Nevertheless, you should probably include a screenshot of what your notebook looks like after doing all of that.

Comment: Use MatrixForm for displaying purposes only. Do not copy its result to use in any further calculation whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd. But what should I do instead ? Thanks

Comment: Nevertheless, I am surprised that `AdjacencyGraph[]` cannot interpret a matrix rendered in two-dimensional form; the last time I used *Mathematica* (more than a year ago), there were no troubles with matrices and graph functions.

Comment: Well try it, you will see.

Comment: Anyway, anyone got an idea of how I can use the information in the adjacency matrix ?

Comment: Well, as I asked earlier, please post a screenshot of what your notebook looks like to assist with diagnosis. Also maybe mention your version number and OS. (The last time I tried this was on version 8.)

Comment: couldn't find how to post a screenshot. Sorry

Comment: So take a screenshot, post it to a site like [imgur](http://imgur.com), and then link to it here.

Comment: Thanks !  Here's the link:  http://imgur.com/RNgrR8a  On the left picture the original random graph and the matrix; on the right picture I use the same matix but I added a link between nodes 3 and 6, and when I plot the using the new matrix I get the original graph without link 3-6.

Comment: Okay… why is this in Word and not *Mathematica*? That may be one reason why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is `MatrixForm`. It is hiding the fact that the output of `AdjacencyMatrix` is actually a `SparseArray` object.

When you copy the pretty-printed output of `MatrixForm` and modify it, you are actually NOT modifying the underlying `SparseArray` object that stores the matrix. When you feed that apparently modified output back into `GraphPlot`, the definition of the graph from the adjacency matrix is still the original one, so `GraphPlot` give you the original graph...

`MatrixForm` is only supposed to be used for printing, but its results should not be used again for input, as @Sjoerd mentioned in his comment.

Here is what you can do instead:

```
SeedRandom[1];

g = RandomGraph[{8, 13}];
GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True]
adjmat = AdjacencyMatrix[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will notice that the last output, corresponding to your adjacency matrix, is a `SparseArray`:

```
SparseArray[< 26 >, {8, 8}]
```

You can turn that into a normal matrix using `Normal`:

```
Normal[adjmat]

(* Out: 
{
{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}
}
*)
```

Now copy that output, modify it, then feed it back into a new `GraphPlot` (here I arbitrarily changed the values in the first row to all ones):

```
GraphPlot[{
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
  {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}
}, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @J. M. Yeah, it was only when I stripped the `MatrixForm` that I realized as well. On the face of it, however, I can see the frustration on the OP's part with changing the `MatrixForm` output, and not having his changes reflected in the underlying object...

Comment: +1 for revealing a useful gotcha... now I know to look out for this in the future!

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is very clear ! It's strange though that Mathematica did not come up with something a bit simpler for such a simple operation. Thanks again

Comment: @seb You are welcome. MatrixForm is a tricky beastie... If you think that my contribution answers your question well, you might want to consider upvoting it (when you achieve enough reputation points) and accepting it (which you can do at any time). Further instructions are at this link ([What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)), if you are unfamiliar with this site.

Comment: Done ! Thanks again

Comment: @seb Thank you for the accept!

Comment: As you seem to know about graphs, I have another question: do you know if there is a way that I can move around the nodes of the graph ? In your example for instance, if I wish to move node 1 upwards on the drawing, can I ?

Comment: @seb, for moving nodes around, you'll want to look at setting the `VertexCoordinates` option; if there is a way to interactively move nodes around in the current version, I haven't heard about it.

Comment: @seb I agree with @J. M. I don't know of a way to do it by hand. You could try out some different automatic layouts though. Instead of using `GraphPlot`, simply use `Graph[g]` to generate a representation of your graph object, then right click on the diagram it creates and explore the graphical options available e.g. under "Graph Layout".

Comment: Ok, thanks to both of you.